# How can I solve this using _.filter?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Please help.

I'm trying to solve the following problem:
**Use _.filter to return all strings in an array that start with the letter 'Z'.**

Here's what I have so far (I'm a novice):

```
var arr = ['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina', 'Zelda']
_.filter(arr, function(v) {
    return ...
```

Comment: [String methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2) - which one would you use to get the first char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```js
var arr = ['Steve', 'Sally', 'George', 'Gina', 'Zelda'];
var filtered = _.filter(arr, function(v) {
    return typeof v === 'string' && v[0] === 'Z';
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, this is a simple question, but your solution is not perfect. "return all strings in an array..." doesn't mean there are always _only_ strings.